# Calling jsp file based on user input

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I have a html page with a radiobuttonlist.Based on the user's input on that I need to provide various input options..I have created JSP pages for the various options and was trying to use javascript.I am able to pass the input checked to the js script but couldnt proceed furthur.I am using struts2 framework.Can someone suggest some way of doing it

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags"  prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">  

function getvalues(input){
document.write(input);}
</script>  

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="Register">


<s:select name="product" list="productList" listKey="productName"
    listValue="productName" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select"
    label="Select a product"  />
<s:radio name="option" label="Select Change:" list="{'option1','option2','option3'}" onclick="getvalues(this.value)" />
 <s:submit />
```

Comment: post some code so we can help

Comment: you would check and forward the request from the base servlet/filter/jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You can show different JSP's based on your selected value.You can simply call you action class and return results based on your inputs.

### JavaScript

```
function getvalues(input){

    $.ajax({
         type : 'GET',
         url : you action URL+'?input='+input
         success : function(response) {
            // show content on success
          },
          error : function(e) {
        }
   });
}
```

### Action Class

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{
 private String input;
 private String view;

// getter and setter for view and input

 public String execute() throws Exception {
    //use input to determine which JSP you want to show
    setView(JSP you want to show based on value of input);
    return SUCCESS;
 }

}
```

### Struts.xml

```
 <action name="Your Action" class="Your Class">
    <result>${view}</result>
 </action>
```

Here i am using `${view}` using as dynamic value as this is being set in your action class and based on the value you have used in your action class, corresponding JSP will be picked by S2 to render your view.